# Switching battery and main power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, schottky

I have Li-ion Battery (12.6V) and 15V power supply, also DC-DC buck converter set to 12.6V as charger for Li-ion Battery. My load can take both 12.6V and 15V. I want to use Li-ion battery as power source. But when needed, i will turn on my power supply and both charge my battery and feed the load. I want to use dual schottky diode to prevent back currents and low voltage drops. Is my schematic corrent? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: No. Your 12.6V supply should also connect the "top" of the load. The "bottom" of the load will connect to your return. Look at your schematic, where is current supposed to flow?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited the scheme.

Comment: An Ideal Diode dual FET IC is best for current sharing and isolation but the battery needs a current sense to cutoff CV charging degrading cell life from extended durations above CC mode into CV.

Comment: A DC-DC converter is not a li-ion charger and thus should not be connected to charge li-ion batteries. Does it even limit current?

Comment: Yes. This dc dc converter has current limiter and cc/cv mode. Actually this system is already working, but with two usual high current diodes. I'm interested is it okay to change them to one dual schottky diode.